# JWT Token created is not matching decoded in Flask

Tags: flask, jwt

I`m receiving 401 in my JWT requests to the method get user infos from token (), but the tokens doesnt seem to be the same.

I already made the following checks: 1. Checked the token string is exactly the same both in the localStorage and in the create_access_token result. 2. The secret key is the same both in the token creation and in the token decoding 3. The algorithm used for encoding is also the same as the one used for decoding

What else can I do to fix it?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'example-key'

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    # Extract the username and password from the request
    user_email = request.get_json(silent=True).get('user_email', None)
    user_password = request.get_json(silent=True).get('user_password', None)

    # Validate the credentials using the UserController
    user = UserController().find_user_by_user_email_and_password(user_email, user_password)
    if user is False:
        return jsonify({'login': False}), 401

    # Calculate the expiration time
    exp = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=7)

    # Create a JWT token with the user identity and expiration time
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user['user_id'], expires_delta=timedelta(days=7))
    print("Token: '" + str(access_token) + "'")

    # Return the JWT token in the response
    return jsonify({'access_token': access_token}), 200


@app.route('/get_user_infos_from_token', methods=['GET'])
def get_user_infos_from_token():
    try:
        authorization_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        token = authorization_header.split(" ")[1]
        print("Token: '" + str(token) + "'")
        decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=['HS256'])
        
        user_id = decoded_token['identity']
        user = UserController().find_user_by_user_id(user_id)
        if user is None:
            return jsonify({'error': 'User not found'}), 404
        return jsonify(user), 200
    except:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid token'}), 401


the method below I'm using to authenticate the user, generate the token and insert in localStorage: 

async login(){
                let self = this;

                axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login',  {
                      user_email: self.email
                    , user_password: self.password
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.access_token);
                    console.log(response.data)
                    self.login_error = '';
                    window.alert('Uhu, deu certo! Vou te redirecionar para a página principal.');
                    self.$router.push({path: '/'});
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    self.login_error = 'Usuário ou senha incorretos. Tente novamente.';
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },


and the method below I am using to get the infos from the user, based on the token that is in the localStorage, that was created during the authentication.

mounted(){
            if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null == true){

                let self = this;

                const token = localStorage.getItem('token').toString();
                console.log(token);

                axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get_user_infos_from_token', {
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } 
                }).then(response => {
                    self.user_data = response.data;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });

                localStorage.setItem('user_data', self.user_data);
                self.user_auth_flag = true;
            }
        },

What do I need to do to make sure the jwt decoder will use the same secret key and algorithm to decode the token generated during the authentication?
```

..

Answer (score 0):

you did not post your jwt create and validate function. I have a jwt_helper class, you can use it for your own purpose:
PyJWT==1.4.2

```
import jwt
import os
class JWTHelper:
    @staticmethod
    def gen_auth_token(identity, email) -> str:
        return JWTHelper.encode_auth_token({
            "id": identity,
            "email": email,
            "expired": Helper.get_now_unixtimestamp() + 60 * 60,  # expire in 1h,
        })

    @staticmethod
    def encode_auth_token(payload) -> str:
        secret_key = os.environ["JWT_SECRET"] # your secret
        print(secret_key)
        """
        Generates the Auth Token
        :return String
        """
        try:
            return jwt.encode(
                payload,
                secret_key,
                algorithm='HS256'
            ).decode('utf-8')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    @staticmethod
    def decode_auth_token(token):
        secret_key = os.environ["JWT_SECRET"]
        """
        Decode the auth token
        """
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, secret_key, algorithms='HS256')
            return payload
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise Unauthorized(message="Please log in again.")

            # return None

    @staticmethod
    def validate_token(token: str):
        data = JWTHelper.decode_auth_token(token)
        print(data)
        if not data:
            raise Unauthorized(message='invalid token')

        expired = data.get("expired") or None
        user_id = data. Get("id") or None

        if expired is None or user_id is None:
            raise Unauthorized(message='invalid token')
        if expired < Helper.get_now_unixtimestamp():
            raise Unauthorized(message='token expired')
```

use your class

```
token = JWTHelper.gen_auth_token(
                identity=1,
                email="tuandao864@gmail.com",
                role_id=1,
            )
validate = JWTHelper.validate_token(auth_token)
```